# Kivy places widgets slightly differently through Python and Kivy language. Am I missing something?

Tags: python, kivy

I just picked up Kivy and encountered this problem. If there is a better way to achieve what I'm trying to in general I'd love to hear about it, though.

What I've noticed is that, when I add a widget to another widget, if I do so through Python code it will be slightly at a different position than had I done so through Kivy. I'll paste my code below (it's pretty short right now) and you can just try it yourself and you'll see what I mean.

client.py:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1') # current kivy version

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '360')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '640')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.vector import Vector
from random import randint

class Bird(Widget):
    '''
        Bird Widget defines each sprite. / Test version: blue and red cards
        Defined attributes:
            SIZE
            POSITION
            (COLOR)
        Upade the position of this widget individually every 0.7 seconds with 60 fps
    '''

    # set attributes
    border_color = (1,1,1)
    r = NumericProperty(0)
    g = NumericProperty(0)
    b = NumericProperty(0)
    color = ReferenceListProperty(r, g, b) # initial color = red // maybe make it random

    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(-3)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Bird, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pick_color()

    # Randomly generate 0 or 1, and pick a color based on that
    def pick_color(self):
        color_num = randint(0,1)

        if color_num == 0: # blue
            self.color = (0,0,1)
        elif color_num == 1: # red
            self.color = (1,0,0)

    # Move the widget by -3y increment at 60 fps
    def increment(self, dt):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos

    def move(self):

        # While the sprite moves at 60 fps, the movement is "cancelled" after 0.3 seconds
        # This event sequence is refreshed every 0.7 seoncds in MainApp class
        move = Clock.schedule_interval(self.increment, 1.0/60.0)
        stop = Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: move.cancel(), 0.3)


class GameMain(Widget):
    '''
        Contains two functions: ADD_NEW_BIRD() and UPDATE().
        All controls happen in this widget
        Not using kivy.screen because there is only one screen used

        ADD_NEW_BIRD() adds a new bird to list_of_birds AND add it as a child widget to the GameMain Widget. UPDATE() calls MOVE() (Bird Widget) and receives events

        Create global variable limit = 0; if limit == 4, game over; variable accessed in update function, which checks whether the limit has been reached. If the player makes the right decision, then limit -= 1
    '''

    limit = 0

    def add_new_bird(self):
        self.new_bird = Bird(center_x=self.center_x, center_y=self.height/1.5)
        print (self.center_x, self.height)
        self.new_bird.pick_color()
        self.add_widget(self.new_bird)

    def update(self, dt):
        for bird in self.children:
            bird.move()

        self.add_new_bird()

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):    
        game = GameMain()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 0.7)
        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.9

<Bird>:
    size: 70, 80
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: self.border_color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
        Color:
            rgb: self.color
        Rectangle:
            size: root.width - 10, root.height - 10
            pos: root.x + 5, root.y + 5

<GameMain>
    Bird:
        center_x: root.center_x
        center_y: root.height / 1.5
```

The code does exactly what I want it to do (I'm going to touch on the z-values later) except that the very first card is slightly off to the left. I'm just really confused because `center_x: root.center_x` in `main.kv` should not be any different from `Bird(center_x=self.center_x` in `client.py` as far as I understand. I've tried initializing the first instance of `Bird()` inside of an init function like so:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(GameMain, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.bird = Bird(center_x=self.center_x, center_y=self.height/1.5)
    self.bird.pick_color()
    self.add_widget(self.bird)
```

And the problem was still there! If anyone could explain what's going on/what I'm doing wrong and maybe even suggest a better way to approach this, I'd appreciate it.

Just in case you're curious, I need to add widgets directly from Python code because I need the app to constantly produce a new card at a constant time interval. The first card, however, is initialized in the Kivy file for the sake of simplicity. To be fair it works pretty well except for the offset. And lastly I'm not using a Layout because I wasn't sure which one to use... I did lay my hands on FloatLayout for a bit but it didn't seem like it was going to fix my problem anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When constructed, Widget has an initial size of (100, 100). If you change  size from this:

```
<Bird>:
    size: 70, 80
```

to this:

```
<Bird>:
    size: 100, 80
```

rectangles will align correctly. Initial rectangle, created in kv file, is centered at the parent window, other ones that are created in Python code are offset to the left.

If you change Bird constructor in Python code from this:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Bird, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.pick_color()
```

to this (effectively overriding the default widget size from (100, 100) to be (50,50)):

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.size = (50, 50)
    super(Bird, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.pick_color()
```

you'll notice that rectangles created in Python code will shift to the right. Change kv file from:

```
<Bird>:
    size: 70, 80
```

to:

```
<Bird>:
    size: 50, 80
```

which matches (new) initial widget size of (50,50) in width, all rectangles will be aligned again.

Solution to your problem would be to leave all as is, except to set `size` for new birds in Python to be equal to that in kv file:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.size = (70, 80)
    super(Bird, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.pick_color()
```

and all will work as intended.

This all means that `size` property from kv file is not applied to your Python-side created Birds, only to the one created by kv declaration. Is this Kivy bug or maybe you are missing one more step in the Python code to make Builder apply `size` from kv file to Python-created Birds, I have no idea right now.

In my experience, at this point of Kivy development, mixing too much kv and Python code will result in these kind of weird issues you have here. It is best to either handle all view related stuff in kv or to ditch kv completely and build everything in Python.

Some things don't work at all in kv, i.e. setting `cols` property of `GridLayout` (v1.9.1).

Personally, for now, I stick to well organized Python code to build UI and don't use kv files almost at all.

Hope this helps a bit...

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using a workaround, but knowing this would've saved me a TON of headache. Also that part about not mixing too much kivy and python - I'm seeing that issue right now, with Popups. I'd love to have that ideal "separation" (kivy handles all UI stuff, python handles logic) but since I am adding widgets dynamically quite often I end up using python more. Maybe I should ditch the kivy file completely..